# Phase noise of a digital PLL

Tags: noise, matlab, pll, phase, noise-spectral-density

I assume the reader is aware of how a DPLL works.

- The DPLL oscillates with a frequency of \$F_{out}\$.
- The DCO free running frequency is \$F_{free}\$.
- In the model of our DPLL we've only considered the TDC quantization noise.
- The instantaneous frequency deviation is given, which is the change from \$F_{free}\$ to any frequency we want it to lock onto, say \$F_{out}\$. The following plot shows a 1MHz change until it locks:

[image]

where CKR with the average frequency \$F_R\$ is the retimed clock used to synchronize the internal DPLL operations. The index k represents the kth occurrence of the CKR's rising edge. Let's say that this curve is stored in a vector called `ifd`, which has a length of k, obviously.

Now given the frequency deviation I'm not sure as to how I could find the *power spectral density* of the output phase noise, which is mainly due to the TDC quantization with a limited resolution.

I understand that the phase is the time integral of the frequency multiplied by 2\$\pi\$, or \$\phi=2\pi\int{ifd \ dt}\$. We know ifd so we know \$\phi\$ by integration. Now in the context of MATLAB language the PSD is obtained

```
phi=2*pi*cumsum(ifd)/FR;
pn=f(phi);
% PSD
fs=10*FR;
[pxx,f]=pwelch(pn,[],[],[],fs,'onesided');
XdB=10*log10(pxx);
```

I'm actually stuck at the second line, where I don't know what `f` should be. Does anyone know what I should replace `f` with? Is that simply a `sin` function or something more complex than that?

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: I recall the phase in an FM system is deltaF/Fmodulation. Here you have a discretized FM system.